# installing PIP on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux with Python 3.8 E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, python3, pip

**Trying to install pip** with **Ubuntu version 20.04**, **Python version** 3.8 on my Oracle virtual box.
Tried everything to install pip but failed

**Steps tried**

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Also tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Error both times**

> python3-pip is not available but is being used by another candidate. This may mean that the package has been obsolete, has been missing or is only available from another source.
>
> E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) If not, please edit your question to clearly explain what you tried. "Everything" is much too vague.

Comment: Found in https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=python3-pip 'universe', do you have it enabled? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (or see duplicate link)